# Angular 6 HttpInterceptor interface fail on production

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I'm using `HttpInterceptor` interface to add authorisation header on http petitions,

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private localStorage: LocalStorageService,
        private sessionStorage: SessionStorageService
    ) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (!request || !request.url || (/^http/.test(request.url) && !(SERVER_API_URL && request.url.startsWith(SERVER_API_URL)))) {
            return next.handle(request);
        }

        const token = this.localStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken') || this.sessionStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken');
        if (!!token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }

}
```

my app module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      VistaModule,
      LayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Locally it works perfectly but it fails when generates `prod dist` and uploads on server.
Any petition obtains headers: `Object, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized"`

Can you help me?

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to check what the value in local storage is, what is sent in the request. Add logs to your server to see what it gets as token, what it expects.

Comment: I think it should be `if(token)` and not `if(!token)` ...

Comment: Do not clone request and assign it to same object reference. use something like  const anotherReq=request.clone();

Answer (score 2):

Declare your Interceptor to be provided in root:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

instead of using just:

```js
@Injectable()
```

It means that your interceptor will be available in all your application, this in the case you have another module for product which could be the problem.

Check more details on: [Angular Providers](https://angular.io/guide/providers)